# No route matches when trying to sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm having troubles with routes in Ruby on Rails. I've configured routes this way

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    resource :registrations, only: [:show, :create]
    resource :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resource :confirmations, only: [:show]
  end
end
```

And I have a RegistrationsController where I have two endpoints (new, create)

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_filter :authenticate!

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = t("registrations.user.success")
      redirect_to :root
    end
  end
end
```

But when I do rails s and I put localhost:3000/users/registrations/create or new I get a "no route matches". And I think the route exist because If I do raake routes I get this

```
registrations POST   /users/registrations(.:format) registrations#create
              GET    /users/registrations(.:format) registrations#show
```

I know it should be a silly mistake but I don't get it. I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define routes for registrations, you're limiting it to just `[:show, :create]`:

```
resource :registrations, only: [:show, :create]
```

But your controller (correctly!) is presuming that there are two routes: `new` (to show the registration form) and `create` (to create the new user). You need to change your routes so that they match your controller actions:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    resource :registrations, only: [:new, :create] # Updated this line!
    resource :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resource :confirmations, only: [:show]
  end
end
```

Comment: You are right. It didn't make sense a show without and endpoint in the controller. Thank you